# How to disable X's an O's in Javascript Tic Tac Toe game

Tags: javascript, tic-tac-toe

For short, I know the question doesn't make that sense, let me clear things up, if i click on the O's it changes to X and vise versa how can i fix this?
Like I don't know how to disable them to stay put and also do you guys know how can I reset the game with a for loop instead of doing it manually

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
      <script text="javascript" src="tic.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <center>
      <body>
         <h1 style="font-family:arial;">Tic-Tac-Toe</h1>
         <table>
            <tr>
               <td id = "case1" onclick="display_input('case1')"></td>
               <td id = "case2" onclick="display_input('case2')"></td>
               <td id = "case3" onclick="display_input('case3')"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td id = "case4" onclick="display_input('case4')"></td>
               <td id = "case5" onclick="display_input('case5')"></td>
               <td id = "case6" onclick="display_input('case6')"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td id = "case7" onclick="display_input('case7')"></td>
               <td id = "case8" onclick="display_input('case8')"></td>
               <td id = "case9" onclick="display_input('case9')"></td>
            </tr>
         </table>
         <footer>
            <p>Copyright&copy; 2014</p>
         </footer>
      </body>
   </center>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var player_one = 1;
function display_input(square){ 

    if ( player_one == 1 ){
        document.getElementById(square).innerHTML = "X";
        player_one = 0;

    } else {
        document.getElementById(square).innerHTML = "O";    
        player_one = 1;
    }
}

function reset() {

    document.getElementById("case1").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case2").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case3").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case4").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case5").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case6").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case7").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case8").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("case9").innerHTML = "";
}
```

Comment: This is extremely easy - taking any web development course should have been enough to figure it out. Simply check for the value upon onclick using getElementById and use an if statement.

Comment: Delegate the listener to the parent table, then set the content of each cell based on whether it's already got an "O" or "X" and which player clicked on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always check that the square element is empty, and if it is not, then don't perform any action:

```
function display_input(square) {
    //We get the associated DOM element
    var element = document.getElementById(square);

    //If the element already contains something, then don't change it
    if(element.innerHTML != "") return;

    if(player_one == 1) {
        element.innerHTML = "X";
        player_one = 0;
    } else {
        element.innerHTML = "O";
        player_one = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite the onclick function of the square by adding the following to display_input(square)

```
document.getElementById(square).onclick = function() {return};
```

Comment: or just `...onclick = ''`.